# stanford Core NLP: Splitting sentences from text

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentence

I am new to stanford Core NLP. I would like to use it for splitting sentences from text in English, German,French. Which class does this work?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the lower level classes that handle this, you can look at the [tokenizer documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml). At the CoreNLP level, you can just use the Annotator's "tokenize,ssplit".

Comment: What is the simplest way to get the list of resulting sentences from the pipeline? I can get List<CoreMap>, but not sure how to get List<String> sentences.

Comment: I found the solution: doing "sentence.get(TextAnnotation.class);" where sentence is a CoreMap.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the documentation on the [main Stanford NLP page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)? About half way down, it provides an example of almost the exact thing you're looking for. The example not only splits sentences, but also words.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `BreakIterator` from `java.text` package...... to split Sentences, Lines, Words, Characters...etc

**See this link:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html

Comment: it didn't know it before. i will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, there are a lot of subtleties with NLP parsing that a simple strategy such as BreakIterator might not handle correctly. For example, would you correctly handle a sentence like `The bread costs $4.99.` or `"What is the matter?" asked the mother.` If you are ok with a naive solution, BreakIterator will do just fine. If you want to handle these cases more robustly, the Stanford NLP library is a great idea.

Comment: In your examples BreakIterator does the best - it properly gets the words and ignores "$4.99", just what I need when I want to extract **words**. Maybe there are some other examples where Stanford NLP is better?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = pipeline.process(SENTENCES)
    .get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);    
    // I just gave a String constant which contains sentences.
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
            System.out.println(sentence.toString());
    }
```